# Xcode Multiple Targets into One macOS App

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, sfml, xcode-target

I have been coding with the C++ Framework SFML (https://www.sfml-dev.org/index.php) for a little over a year now, and wish to try and get a game developed and post it to the Mac App Store for both Intel & Apple Silicon Architectures.

With SFML currently I have the ability to target one or the other, but not both. Both have dylibs available: (https://artifacts.sfml-dev.org/by-branch/master/)

Is it possible to have multiple targets in Xcode, one targeting x86_64 and the other arm64 and have Xcode merge these targets into One macOS App? I couldn't find any good information answering my question so I thought I would ask and see if this is possible.

Current Xcode version is 12.5.1 on Big Sur 11.4.

Any help would be awesome. Thanks.